Is it possible to have Azure policy compare the tag value of a specific tag key?
I am trying to write an Azure policy that inherits the tag value of a specific tag from the resource group to the resource.
For example, please consider the following:
I have a virtual machine with the tag Application: Appname1
This VM is in the resource group with the tag Application: Appname2
I need a policy that checks if the tag value of the VM(Appname1) matches the tag value of the resource group(Appname2). The operation to change the value is simple enough, but I'm having a hard time refining the if/check to get the tag values.
The built-in inherit policy has the following rule:
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "notEquals": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('tagName')]]"
          },
          {
            "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('tagName')]]",
            "notEquals": ""
          }
        ]
      },

This check that the RG tag key is not empty and that the tag key for the resource does not equal the tag key of the RG.
This only compares the tag key or tag name of the resources/RG and not the tag values.

I found a solution to this. Removing the second clause above and leave the following clause will compare the value at the resource level to the resourcegroup level.
{
"field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
"notEquals": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('tagName')]]"
}

I do agree with SRoberts ,Inheriting the tag value of a specific tag from the resource group by removing second clause from the default policy.


Is it possible to have Azure policy compare the tag value of a specific tag key?

You can use below policy to inherits the tag value of a specific tag from the resource group to the resources.
    {
      "mode": "Indexed",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
              "exists": "false"
            },
            {
              "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('tagName')]]",
              "notEquals": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "append",
          "details": [
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
              "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('tagName')]]"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "tagName": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Tag Name",
            "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
          }
        }
      }
    }

Make sure to enable remediation while assigning the policy and assign the role to append the tags.

Policy assignment:

